# Joomla Site very slow

Tags: joomla3.0

i'm struggling onto a problem that i can't find a way ti fix. I'm currently running joomla 3.4.5 and a gantry based theme. I tried minifying CSS, JS and HTML and also optimize the images with the google insight tool. 
i've done a debug system and it shows that
`Application: beforeRenderModule mod_rocknavmenu`
implies 21.7 seconds ..... I think that is the issue .... how can i solve that?
The site is [this](http://www.cucu3.it)
Thank you for your supoprt

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site? Also I would recommend using a CDN. Make sure the CDN is utilizing browser caching for the images, CSS and JS files.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the site is slow due to your hosting.

Also news01.png and news02.png are taking several seconds each to come through.

Update all of your extensions, out of date extensions can impact performance.

Check your slow query log, CPU, and memory usage on your server. Those will tell you more about potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

Found realy easy solution - just disable System - Model plugin